# jquery not working in JSP page

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

i have a HTML code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#username").keyup(function(){

    var username = $("#username").val().trim();

    if(username=="")
    {
         $("#usernameerrortext").html("Username should not be empty");
         return false;
    }
    else if(/[!@#$%\\^&*(){}[\]<>?\/|\-]/.test(username))
    {
        $("#usernameerrortext").html("Username should not contain special charatcers");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#usernameerrortext").html("");
        return true;
    }
    });

    $("#password").keyup(function(){
    var password = $("#password").val().trim();

    if(password=="")
    {
         $("#passworderrortext").html("Password should not be empty");
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#passworderrortext").html("");
        return true;
    }
    });
});
</script>
<br/>Username:<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
<font color="red"><div id="usernameerrortext"></div></font>
<br>
Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
<font color="red"><div id="passworderrortext"></div></font>
```

This is working perfectly as a html page. but when i pasted this code in a JSP file like the below , my jquery is not working,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>HDB SBBS</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#username").keyup(function(){

    var username = $("#username").val().trim();

    if(username=="")
    {
         $("#usernameerrortext").html("Username should not be empty");
         return false;
    }
    else if(/[!@#$%\\^&*(){}[\]<>?\/|\-]/.test(username))
    {
        $("#usernameerrortext").html("Username should not contain special charatcers");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#usernameerrortext").html("");
        return true;
    }
    });

    $("#password").keyup(function(){
    var password = $("#password").val().trim();

    if(password=="")
    {
         $("#passworderrortext").html("Password should not be empty");
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#passworderrortext").html("");
        return true;
    }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <center>
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="LoginServlet" method="post">
            <br/>Username:<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <font color="red"><div id="usernameerrortext"></div></font>
            <br/>Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
            <font color="red"><div id="passworderrortext"></div></font>
            <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

help needed here.

Comment: load the jsp on chrome and inspect the page (right click and hit inspect element). see if you can figure out the issue. else put the issue here.

Comment: any error you are getting , try to look into your browser console, if you are using chrome, then inspect element and see if you have any error.if so please let us know

Comment: Define **not working**. What is the error you see in the javascript console?

Comment: Have you tried with `<script type="text/javascript">` rather than just `<script>`?

Comment: use if(password==="") for comparison,

and why are you using such old(1.5.2) lib of jquery BTW.

Comment: @kalai Can you tell what is the error message thrown?

Comment: i am getting only the login page.i am running it inside eclipse. i deployed outside and tried. it is not working there too. java script   which i used is not getting executed.

Comment: i am not getting any error. but my javascript  is not executing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#username").on('focusout',function(){

var username = $("#username").val().trim();

if(username==="")
{    
     $("#usernameerrortext").html("Username should not be empty");
     return false;
}
else if(/[!@#$%\\^&*(){}[\]<>?\/|\-]/.test(username))
{
    $("#usernameerrortext").html("Username should not contain special charatcers");
    return false;
}
else
{
    $("#usernameerrortext").html("");
    return true;
}
});

$("#password").on('focusout',function(){
var password = $("#password").val().trim();

if(password==="")
{
     $("#passworderrortext").html("Password should not be empty");
     return false;
}
else
{
    $("#passworderrortext").html("");
    return true;
}
});
});
```

I have created a demo fiddle for you here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TbVkv/396/)

You need to include the jquery lib in head tag of the page you want to run this script.

For that nothing much has to be done just add this line in the head tag `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">`

Comment: I think @kalai DONT have problem with script. When the extension of file .jsp then nothing is displayed in the browser. If it is the .html, then it works. You have written the html code in the FIDDLE.

Comment: The script kalai provided isn't working on html page either..
I just copy pasted the html code @kalai posted to check the Jquery.

Comment: Actuelly kalai didn't mention the problem exactly. Is it the script problem or extension problem.

Comment: problem is i dont know to use jquery plugin.can you please tel me how to resolve it. is there anything that i need to add in my dynamic web project inorder to run my jquery. i think i am getting source from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js so i dont need to add anything it seems. correct me if i am wrong